# Pass facebook AccessToken by Retrofit

Tags: android, facebook, kotlin, retrofit2, facebook-access-token

I'm trying to get posts from facebook page using Retrofit but I can't pass Access token and every time I get an error `io.reactivex.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: HTTP 400 Bad Request`

This is my code:

RetroAPI:

```
@GET("{page_id}/feed")
fun getPosts(@Path("page_id") pageId : String,
             @Header("access_token") authToken : AccessToken)
             : Observable<Posts>
```

Set Access Token:

```
 AccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(AccessToken("AppToken", "AppID","userID",null,null,null,null,null))
```

Get data:

```
  var pagePosts : Observable<Posts> = facebook.getPosts("pageID", AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken())
    pagePosts.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe({result ->
                var a : Posts = result
                var b : List<Data> = result.data
                Log.d("Posts A","${a.data[1].id}")
                Log.d("Data B", "$b")
            })
```

Set RetrofitAPI:

```
private val facebook : RetroAPI
    init{
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/")
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()

        facebook = retrofit.create(RetroAPI::class.java)
    }
```

Comment: I think You need to add graph api version to base Url: https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/

Comment: @RafalMalek it dosen't work at all

Comment: have you tested this call with some http client tool like postman? or with graph api explorer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally access_token is sent as a query param to authenticate your request.

However you can also send a header in the form

Authorization: Bearer XXX

But AFAIK sending access_token as a header is unsupported.

Comment: I change `@Header` to `@Query` but I still have the error. Maybe my token is badly declared ?

Comment: Okay, so I was sending bad access token. I change `@Header` to `@Query` and `accessToken` from `AccessToken` to `String` and send only `AppToken`. I would give you an upvote but I dont have enought rep :(